# On Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I was studying Stirling numbers of second came across the general equation distribution of $n$ distinct things in $k$ identical subsets  is $$S(n,k) = \frac{k^n - \binom{k}{1}(k-1)^n + \binom{k}{2}(k-2)^n - \cdots + (-1)^{k-1}\binom{k}{k-1}(1)^n}{k!}$$ but here every subset contains at least one thing.
Is there is any equation which invalidates this condition? I mean $k$ subsets can include zero too.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your formula wasn't quite right so I edited. Not sure what you mean by "Is there any equation which invalidates this condition?" The Stirling numbers of the second kind are defined to count distributions of $n$ elements into $k$ *non-empty* sets. If you could elaborate on that question in quotes a little it might help.

Comment: @N.Shales second kind equation deals with distribution of object in the subsets such that each subset contain atleast one object, I need equation in which follows without 'atleast one' mean if there is two subset one subset can  also contain no object

Comment: @DarkKnight: Ok, bear in mind that the order of subsets is not important then you want to calculate distributions of $n$ elements into $k$, $k-1$, $k-2$, ... , $1$ subsets having at least 1 element in each (respectively with 0 empty sets, 1 empty set, 2 empty sets, ... , $k-1$ empty sets). How might you calculate this using $S(n,k)$, $S(n,k-1)$, ... $S(n,1)$? If you have distinguishable subsets then the problem is considerably easier, being just $k^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Stirling's number $S_k^n$ represents the number of ways that $\{1, \ldots , n \}$ can be partitioned into exactly $k$ non-empty subsets.

If you allow for exactly one empty subset, then the number of allowable partitions grows to include partitions consisting of $\emptyset$ *and* all possible partitions of $k-1$ non-empty subsets. Thus the number becomes $S_k^n + S_{k-1}^n$.

If you allow for at most two empty subsets, the number becomes $S_k^n + S_{k-1}^n + S_{k-2}^n$.

If you allow for at most three empty subsets, the number becomes $S_k^n + S_{k-1}^n + S_{k-2}^n +  S_{k-3}^n$, etc, etc.

If you want to consider $T^n$, the number of ways to partition $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ into $k$ (possibly empty) sets, you simply take
$$T_k^n = \sum_{j=1}^k S_j^n.$$
Note that when $k = n$, this is equal to $B_n - 1$ where $B_n$ is the $n^{th}$ [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). Thus we might call these numbers incomplete Bell numbers, or something along those lines.